# Ant task to write all file names in a directory to a txt file?

Tags: build, ant

I need to write an ant task that goes into the resources directory and writes all the files names to a txt file in the resources directory. Is this possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `pathconvert` and `echo` tasks for this. Here's an example target:

```
<target name="generate-file-list">
    <delete dir="testdir" />

    <mkdir dir="testdir" />
    <mkdir dir="testdir/subdir" />

    <touch file="testdir/file1" />
    <touch file="testdir/file2" />
    <touch file="testdir/file3" />
    <touch file="testdir/subdir/file4" />

    <pathconvert property="testdir.files" pathsep="${line.separator}">
        <fileset dir="testdir" />
    </pathconvert>

    <echo file="filelist.txt" message="${testdir.files}" />
</target>
```

Output in filelist.txt:

```
/home/user/test/testdir/file1
/home/user/test/testdir/file2
/home/user/test/testdir/file3
/home/user/test/testdir/subdir/file4
```

Comment: Would the fileslist.txt be under the resources folder?

Comment: In the above example, the `echo` task simply writes `filelist.txt` to the same folder where the Ant script itself is located, because just the file name and no parent directory was specified. You can specify the directory in the same attribute like `file="resources/filelist.txt"`.